# How do I construct a nonabelian group of order 1575?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I think that it should be a semidirect product of the direct product of any two of the three groups $\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/25\mathbb Z$ and the other one. But which of these will be the normal subgroup and what nontrivial homomorphism should I take? Can someone please give a solution?

Comment: Hmm. It might be easier to break it into four groups and you have two choices here. One would be $\Bbb Z_7$, $\Bbb Z_9$ and $\Bbb Z_5$ semidirected with $\Bbb Z_5$. From there, you could use some sort of action of $\Bbb Z_5$ on the direct product of the other three (via the fact that there is a copy of $\Bbb Z_5$ in there and use that as a way to implement a nontrivial group action). Or you could do the same but break down $\Bbb Z_9$ instead of $\Bbb Z_{25}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a unique nonabelian group of order 21, the semidirect product of $\Bbb Z_7$ and $\Bbb Z_3$. Note that $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z_7) \cong \Bbb Z_6$; take your map to be $\Bbb Z_3 \xrightarrow{\times 2} \Bbb Z_6$. Now take the product of this with, say, $\Bbb Z_{75}$.

Comment: Good call! This is much simpler than my suggestion haha. Though I guess they are philosophically similar.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yup... Keep numbers small, since big numbers are too hard for me :)